# Is "Indeed," at the beginning of a sentence natural?

Tags: sentence-construction

I am French speaker, writing my (physics) PhD dissertation in English.
One of my supervisors read it and mentioned that 'beginning a sentence by "indeed" is not correct or at least not natural'. What do you think?

Comment: It's as natural (or unnatural) as starting an utterance with *"**Yes**."* Which could be perfectly natural *in the right context*, but it's hard to see how either ***Indeed*** or ***Yes*** could be the first word in the first utterance of a ***new conversation***. Both words kinda *need* a prior context to make sense.

Comment: There is nothing incorrect about it. **Indeed**, it's perfectly acceptable when giving additional support for a statement you have just made.

Comment: I've spent the last couple of minutes trying to think of other words that it's difficult to imagine being used as the first word in a conversation-starter, and I'm a bit surprised to realize I can't come up with even *one* in the same league as *Yes* and *Indeed*.

Comment: Even a near-synonym like ***Truly*** is easily incorporated into something like *"**Truly** life-changing experiences aren't very common, in my opinion".* And I've no real problem with *"**Definitely** hot today!"* (eliding initial ***It's***).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caveat: My answer is from the point of view of American English.

Indeed, **indeed** at the start of a sentence is quite unnatural if "natural" is understood to mean "frequently used in spoken English by the man on the street".  It is somewhat "fusty" even in academic writing, where it occurs fairly frequently just as you have used it at the start of a sentence.

It is an emphatic expression, normally used to indicate that what follows next is a fact that is in perfect alignment with your argument.

> The conductor has little operatic experience. Indeed, over his career of thirty years he has conducted only one, *L'Italiana in Londra*.

Comment: You'll hear it used all the time "down my boozer"!

Comment: @BillJ: I'm not familiar with the phrase "down my boozer".  We say "down the shore" to mean "at the beach", and I'm thinking that "my boozer" might refer to a favorite pub? (I've added a caveat to my answer.)

Comment: American English or British English or any standard English, it's all the same.

Comment: @Lambie You comment is too vague for me to make much sense of it.  What is "it"?  Are you saying that AmE and BrE usage of "Indeed" by the "man on the street" is the same?  And I don't mean exclamatory "Indeed, I do" but the emphatic argumentative use, where a (sometimes fairly involved) statement of fact follows upon it.

Comment: @TimR Yes, I am saying the use is the same in all standard varieties of English. And I don't think the man on the street matters here. This expression is usually used in writing or spoken (as in a speech) by people with a college education.

Comment: @Lambie You may think what you think. But it is up to the writer to decide whether the man on the street manners here. That's why I wrote "... **if** 'natural'  is understood to mean 'frequently used by ... the man on the street' "-- to show a possible criterion for "naturalness". But if the writer has a different definition of *natural*, such as "used frequently by contemporary native-speaker academics when writing treatises on the subject I am writing about") then so be it.

Comment: The fact is that the word indeed at the beginning of a sentence refers back to a previous idea. It is just not more complicated than that. Also, non-native OPs often use that word natural when grammatical or standard would be better.

Comment: @Lambie: The question was about whether some speakers would think  a  sentence starting with "Indeed" was *stilted*.  And I offered the fact that the man in the street in the US does not use **indeed**  as it is used in the example sentence about the music conductor that I gave in my answer. Exclamatory **indeed**, he does use,  (Indeed I do!) but not that kind of rhetorical use: Something like this would not be heard: *The bill seems higher than it should be. Indeed, you've charged me twice for the dog chow.

Answer (score 0):

French has an entire style of expository writing where the sentences are laid out with certain conjunctions when presenting an argument, and the term "**en effet"** (**indeed**) is used in many cases after a previous sentence to emphasize or extend an idea.

Sentences in a paragraph will be structured with such terms as D'abord (first), Ensuite (next or then) and En effet and at the end of the paragraph, a phrase *such as* "En conclusion". This is just an example and not intended to be a complete exegesis of this type of French writing.

Be that as it may, in English as in French, you would only use *indeed* (en effet) to add something to an idea from a previous sentence. It would follow on from a previous thought.